# Pass record id from popup vf page to parent vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this below vf page where on click a popup vf page is opening where i am creating a new account.
I want on save button of the pop up vf page, the newly created account record id should get pass to parent vf page lookup field.

apex class

```
public class Accpopup2 
{
    public Account a {get;set;}
    public string status {get;set;}
    public Accpopup2()
    {
      a = new account();  
    }
    public pagereference save()
    {
     Account a = New Account(Name = a.Name, Phone = a.Phone);
     insert a;
     return null;
    }

    public pagereference cancel()
    {
        status = 'true';
          return null;    
    }
}
```

parent vf page -

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accs">
    <script>
      function OpenVfpage(pid){
          var newwindow = window.open('/apex/Accsmallpopup?id='+pid, 'name=_blank','height=500,width=500,left=250,top=100'); 
      newwindow.focus();
     }
    </script>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock >



    ParentAccount : <apex:inputfield value="{!account.ParentAccount__c}" label="ParentAccount"/>

                        <apex:commandButton value="Click" onclick="OpenVfpage('{!account.id}')" reRender="two"/>

            </apex:pageBlock>

        <script>
    function processAccount(accountId){
        console.log('Inside Parent page --> AccountId passed from popup is-->'+accountId);
    }
</script>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Popup vf page -

```
<apex:page controller="Accpopup2" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" id="the">
   <apex:form id="page">
    <apex:pageblock id="close">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:inputfield value="{!a.Name}"/>
         <apex:inputfield value="{!a.Phone}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageblockbuttons >
        <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}" reRender="dyanamicJs"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
            <apex:inputHidden id="pass" value="{!status}"/>
             </apex:pageblock>

            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            if(document.getElementById('the:page:close:pass').getAttribute('value') == 'true')
                {
                    window.top.close();
                }
            </script>   

        <apex:outputPanel id="dyanamicJs">
```

window.opener.processAccount('{!a.Id}');

Comment: If you want to capture newly created account id from popup to Parent window then what's the reason behind this code: onclick="OpenVfpage('{!account.id}')", it looks like you have meshed up with copy-pasting the code without thinking

Comment: Hi Boral.. Can u ignore that part..`I was checking something else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass parameters from popup to parent page. 
Consider below example which will give idea about how you can pass values from popup to parent page.

**Parent Page code**

```
<apex:page >

       <input type="submit" value="Submit" 
              onclick="window.open('/apex/PopupPage', 'name=_blank','height=500,width=500,left=250,top=100'); return false;"/>
    <script>
        function processAccount(accountId){
            console.log('Inside Parent page --> AccountId passed from popup is-->'+accountId);
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Popup Page Code**

```
<apex:page >
    <input type="submit" value="Pass Value" 
              onclick="window.opener.processAccount('THIS_IS_ACCOUNT_ID');"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Output**
[image]

As you can see when the button from popup is clicked, console of parent page is showing the value of parameter passed.

In your case 
lets say your controller account variable name is theAccount. So you can write in popup page.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="dyanamicJs"> 
   <script> window.opener.processAccount('{!theAccount.Id}'); 
   <script> 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Then you can reRender dynamicJs output panel on save of account

Comment: Hi Kiran...If i am creating a new record can we do it in same way above. How to get the inserted record id and pass it..

Comment: @hellraizer Yes you can do in the above way, you need to get the id of created account in popup page. E.g lets say your controller account variable name is theAccount. So you can write in popup page.
<apex:outputPanel id="dyanamicJs">
   <script>
       window.opener.processAccount('{!theAccount.Id}');
   <script>
</apex:outputPanel>

Then you can reRender dynamicJs output panel on save of account.

Comment: Hi Kiran..wht are the changes i need to do in my controller and pop up vf page..can u help..

Comment: @hellraizer Updated solution. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Kiran... I have updated my code what i am using now. Record is getting inserted but the poppage remains there and in console  i am seeing no id.. Can u check where i am doing wrong..

Comment: Hi Hellraizer, tell me where do you want to use the parent account id. Do you want to show here <apex:inputfield value="{!account.ParentAccount__c}" label="ParentAccount"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58727/discussion-between-kiran-machhewar-and-hellraizer).

Comment: Yes i want to show in <apex:inputfield value="{!account.ParentAccount__c}" label="ParentAccount"/>